# Fire bug add on is not supporting new firefox browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

i tried to install Fire bug in my latest Fire fox 51.0.1 version,to my surprise i couldn't see any fire bug option been present at f12 developer console.is there any way to install the same in latest version of Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

In `Firefox 51.0.1` shows the firebug icon always shows deactivated.

So First Solution is, enable firebug [version 2.0.18]

Enter `about:config` in address bar and find

`browser.tabs.remote.autostart` set it `fals`e

`browser.tabs.remote.autostart.1` set it `false`

`browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2` set it `false`

The another solution can be Download old version of firebug from here and install https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/versions/.